# Portable .Net and MONO Differences

Tags: .net, mono

I've been following/using Mono for a while for .NET development in Linux.  After reading about this recent [controversy](http://www.fsf.org/news/dont-depend-on-mono) and the link this article provides to DotGNU Portable .NET  I wanted to know your experiences with both implementations, and what the palpable diferences between these two projects are.  For instance, I had no idea that Portable .NET implemented System.Windows.Forms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think one aspect of the answer is to look at project activity.

Here is Pnet's:
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/dotgnu-pnet/

Here is Mono's:
https://github.com/mono/mono/commits

Pnet seems to get activity a couple of times a week.  Mono gets activity a couple of times an hour.

Pnet's latest release is 0.8 from March '07, Mono's latest release is 2.4.2 this week.

As for controversy, if there are patents that are going to torpedo Mono, they are going to apply equally to Pnet.

Answer (score 4):

Mono is more widely-used, implements more of the BCL and has support from big Linux companies such as Novell.

In practical use, I find that Mono's System.Windows.Forms support is much better.

Answer (score 2):

The FSF's belief that Microsoft is going to force other implementations underground is a bit odd, considering that it is now an open standard:

```
    ECMA-334: C# Language Specification
    ECMA-335: Common Language Infrastructure
    etc, etc, etc..
```

Anyway, Mono is certainly more mature than Portable .NET.

Comment: FSF's concern is not about those standardized parts of .NET, but more about those that not. Microsoft issued a "promise" that they will not enforce those intellectual property rights, but I agree with FSF on this considering Microsoft's history.

Answer (score 2):

Portable.NET project is inactive since 2009.